# How to use xpath extractor in Apache Jmeter?

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I invoke a SOAP service and get a SOAP response XML along with some details on the top. When i use the xpath extractor i get an error message that content is not allowed in prolog.

How can i resolve this issue in jmeter and get the xpath working ?

[image: SOAP Response with some details on top]

[image: Xpath Extractor Configuration]

[image: Error during Xpath Extraction]

Comment: Your question is about extractor or assertion?

Answer (score 0):

That is a generic (and seemingly unhelpful) error message that the SAX XML parser throws when your input XML is not well formed - usually at the start of the document. Prolog is the first line with xml version info.

Check and validate that your response is well formed. It might be something simple like trimming the beginning characters of the string that you're attempting to parse.